# Open sets in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Please how to prove that this set is open $$\{x\in E, d(x,A)<d(x,B)\}$$

Edit: let $x\in E$ such that $d(x,A)<d(x,B)$ i want to prove that there exist $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subset \{x\in E, d(x,A)<d(x,B)\}$

let $y\in B(x,r)$ then $d(x,y)<r$ how to find that $d(y,A)<d(y,B)$ such that $d(x,A)=\inf_{z\in A} d(x,z)$

We have that $|d(x,A)-d(y.A)|\leq d(x,y)$ then we have that $$d(x,A)-r<d(y,A)\leq d(x,A)+r$$ the same thing for B $$d(x,B)-r<d(y,B)\leq d(x,B)+r$$

But how to find that $$d(y,A)<d(y,B)$$

Thank you.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Disjoint sets? Arbitrary sets?

Comment: @StefanHamcke arbitrary sets from a metric space $(E,d)$

Comment: They should be non-empty, otherwise there's a danger of getting $\infty$.

Comment: The $r$ is not "given". You have to *pick* $r$ yourself. It will depend on the point $x$!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma can i choose $r= d(x,B)-d(x,A) $ i don't now if it help

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $r=d(x,B)-d(x,A)$ but i just found $d(y,A)<d(x,B)$ and i need $d(y,A)<d(y,B)$ ? how to do please

Comment: Take an even smaller $r$ (divide by 3, say).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma if i take $r=\frac{d(x,B)-d(x,A)}{3}$ we have $d(x,A)-d(y,A)<d(x,y)<\frac{d(x,B)-d(x,A)}{3}$ the same thing i don't find what i want

Comment: @HennoBrandsma are you there ?

Answer (score 3):

Show as a lemma that $f_A: x \rightarrow d(x,A)$ is continuous, and similarly for $f_B(x) = d(x,B)$. I.e. one can easily show that $|d(x,A) - d(y,A)| \le d(x,y)$, using the triangle inequality twice.

Then your set is $(f_A - f_B)^{-1}[(-\infty, 0)]$, hence open.

Comment: how to see that the set is open by proving that it contains an open ball please

Comment: That way is more complicated. So why do that?

Comment: because i tried to do it but i don't know how , i let $x\in E$ such that $d(x,A)<d(x,B)$ but how to find $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subset \{x\in E, d(x,A)<d(x,B)\}$

Comment: can you help me with my idea see my edite please

Comment: If you decode the proof that $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous, you get what you want. Try that.

Comment: @JustinYoung why i need the continuité of d for my idea ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou it all comes down to a repeated application of triangle inequalities, in the end.

Comment: It's not true that for an arbitrary function $f: X\to \mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(-\infty, 0)$ is open.

Comment: @JustinYoung But it is for continuous ones. And the difference of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: i don't understand how to do for my method

Comment: @Vrouvrou Then try to understand mine.

Comment: i understant your solution

Comment: I find that: $d(x,A)-r<d(y,A)<d(x,A)+r$ how to find that $d(y,A)<d(y,B)$ please

Comment: Let $f(x) = d(x,A) - d(x,B)$.

Comment: @JustinYoung that's essentially what I did yes.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry, my comments are all addressed to the OP , your solution is perfectly clear and nice.

Comment: @JustinYoung what i must see when i let $f(x)=d(x,A)-d(x,B)$ to prove that $d(y,A)<d(y,B)$ ? thank you